# How to reuse Akka TCP connection to write messages?

Tags: scala, tcp, akka

I am trying to figure out some basic functionality using the Akka TCP module - I am also new to Akka. I would like to create a TCP Client actor and then send that actor messages to write data to the TCP channel.

Implementation of TCP Client (very similar to TCP Client example - http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/io-tcp.html#connecting)

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import akka.actor.{Actor, Props}
import akka.io.{IO, Tcp}
import akka.util.ByteString
import com.hca.cdm.log.Logg
import com.hca.cdm.tcp.AkkaTcpClient.{Ping, SendMessage}

object AkkaTcpClient {
  var prop : Props = _
  def props(host :String,port :Int) = {
    if(prop == null) prop = Props(classOf[AkkaTcpClient], new 
InetSocketAddress(host,port))
    prop
  }

  final case class SendMessage(message: ByteString)
  final case class Ping(message: String)
}

class AkkaTcpClient(remote: InetSocketAddress) extends Actor with Logg {
  import akka.io.Tcp._
  import context.system

  info("Connecting to " +  remote.toString)

  val manager = IO(Tcp)
  manager ! Connect(remote)

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case CommandFailed(con: Connect) =>
      error("Connection failed")
      error(con.failureMessage.toString)
      context stop self

    case c @ Connected(remote, local) =>
      info(s"Connection to $remote succeeded")
      val connection = sender
      connection ! Register(self)

      context become {
        case SendMessage(message) =>
          info("Sending message: " + message.utf8String)
          connection ! Write(message)
        case Ping(message) =>
          info("hello: " + message)
        case data: ByteString =>
          info("Sending request data: " + data.utf8String)
          connection ! Write(data)
        case CommandFailed(w: Write) =>
          error("Failed to write request.")
          error(w.failureMessage.toString)
        case Received(data) =>
          info("Received response.")
          info("data: " + data.utf8String)
        case "close" =>
          info("Closing connection")
          connection ! Close
        case _: ConnectionClosed =>
          info("Connection closed by server.")
          context stop self
       }

    case e: Exception =>
      error(e.printStackTrace().toString)

    case t: Throwable =>
      error(t)

    case _ =>
      error("Something else is happening")

  }
}
```

Example of using actor in application

```
val actorSys = ActorSystem.create("MyActorSys")
val tcpActor = actorSys.actorOf(AkkaTcpClient.props(addr, port), "tcpActor")
tcpActor ! SendMessage(ByteString("hello"))
```

This is not working to write messages to the TCP channel. I see `info(s"Connection to $remote succeeded")` messages in the logs, but then nothing happens and the connection closes. Does anyone have any ideas about how to properly set this up? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your code with `host` as `127.0.0.1` produced the following output (I replaced your logging with `println` statements):

```
Connecting to /127.0.0.1:19002
Something else is happening
Connection to /127.0.0.1:19002 succeeded
```

The above output suggested that `tcpActor` was processing the `SendMessage(ByteString("hello"))` message before the connection was established. Therefore, I added a pause before sending the message (as well as a second message):

```
val tcpActor = actorSys.actorOf(AkkaTcpClient.props(addr, port), "tcpActor")
Thread.sleep(1000)
tcpActor ! SendMessage(ByteString("hello"))
tcpActor ! SendMessage(ByteString("hello again"))
```

The output:

```
Connecting to /127.0.0.1:19002
Connection to /127.0.0.1:19002 succeeded
Sending message: hello
Sending message: hello again
```

In another terminal, netcat was listening to the port:

```
> nc -l 19002
hellohello again
```

As you can see, the messages were written to the connection as expected. With a minor tweak, your setup works.

While your overall approach is sound, there are a couple of issues:

- The `props` method unnecessarily uses a `var`. Remove the `var` and simplify `props` to the following:

  ```
  def props(host: String, port: Int) =
    Props(classOf[AkkaTcpClient], new InetSocketAddress(host, port))
  ```
- I don't think your `case e: Exception =>` and `case t: Throwable =>` branches do what you think they do. They do not handle exceptions and errors that occur when the actor is processing a message; they handle messages of type `Exception` and type `Throwable` that are sent to the actor. That is, they come into play if someone performs the following shenanigans:

  ```
  tcpActor ! new RuntimeException("I should not be doing this")
  tcpActor ! new Error("This is Bad")
  ```

  Delete those two branches. The usual way to handle exceptions in an actor is to define a [supervisor strategy](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/scala/fault-tolerance.html).

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for your response, I'll give that a shot. You are totally right about the Exception and Throwable cases, I'll remove them.